# Why is there a single slash in Google Analytics? How do I remove it?

Tags: google-analytics

I have searched for this issue but only found a terminology called "Trailing Slash" and I feel this is not right. I am facing an issue where a single slash is being tracked. How can I remove this please? What is this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

'/' is your homepage of the site/s being tracked.

Comment: So basically my homepage data hits is being duplicated?

Comment: not really, '/' must be your homepage. Are you seeing any other "homepage" element in your pages report?